# Fail to pass datasource expression to subreport

Tags: java, jasper-reports, subreport

I got the error below by passing data source expression to subreport.

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRExpressionEvalException: Error evaluating expression : 
Source text : new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($P{dataSourceHash})
```

Java code:

```
Vector rs =  ..... // return record set from SQL, e.g. select name from table

Map<String, Object> parm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
parm.put("dataSourceHash", new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(rs));
```

Main report:

```xml
<parameter name="dataSourceHash" class="java.util.Collection" >
....

        <subreport>
            <reportElement uuid="b60242b1-6bbb-4b6b-b54d-bf9a32cf3ec5" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="24"/>
            <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($P{dataSourceHash})]]></dataSourceExpression>
        <subreportExpression><![CDATA["C:\\add_template.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
        </subreport>
```

Subreport:

```xml
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{NAME}]]></textFieldExpression>
```

Kindly advise.

Answer (score 0):

In jrxml parameter $P{datasourceHash} declared as **java.util.Collection**.
But really you pass **JRBeanCollectionDataSource** - it is not java.util.Collection.

How should this work?

In subreport exist constructor new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(**DataSource**) ???.
But parameter of this constructor is collection.

One of the possible solutions:

replace

```
parm.put("dataSourceHash", new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(rs));
```

to

```
parm.put("dataSourceHash", rs);
```